# Laravel database migration foreign constrained

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I have below migration for database in Laravel,

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('table_id');
            $table->string('table_number');
            $table->foreignId('section_id')->constrained('sections')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

and it throws below error,

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `200120`.`tables` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `tables` add constraint `tables_section_id_foreign` foreign key (`section_id`) references `sections` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)
```

I am not sure why it references to `sections (id)`, it should reference to `sections (section_id)`

I did as per this document,

[Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

you can [specify](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) the column name you want to build the relation with:

```
$table->foreign('section_id')->references('section_id')->on('sections')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: This is working, but just looking for a new type of ```constrained()``` option as per Doc

Comment: doc said: the constrained method will use conventions to determine the table and column name being referenced

Comment: while your column 'section_id' should be in convention just 'id', rename it to 'id' and it will work